# Detecting differences in images using neural network approach

Tags: neural-network, classification, anomaly-detection

What would be best way to detect difference between 2 images, one image is taken at beginning of process and the other at the end, goal is to detect if there is any difference in the images.

Based on my research neural networks seems good for this type of problem, but I don't have experience using them, I am not sure should this problem be treated as classification or anomaly detection? Also if you have any useful literature/GitHub projects/papers to share I would be thankful.